# Dotnet Nuke Files automatically getting Rollback

Tags: .net, rollbacksegments

The template files like ( Home.ascx) inside Xcillion are getting rolled back to specific date in the Server. What could be the issue?

Comment: This question would benefit from more detail such as what actions are you taking before the rollback occurs?

Comment: We are not doing any action. After every 5 days it is getting rollback automatically. Then we update the latest file and the same issue occurs consequently. Can't identify the problem.